# SOA system and distributed systems

Tags: architecture, soa

Does using Service Oriented Architecture (SOA) in a system mean it is a distributed system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it means the system is distributed in some way. Even if you're only using SOA within your enterprise, the systems are still distributed across multiple services. This would be true even if the services were all on a single computer.

Answer (score 0):

**SOA is a distributed system**: meaning it invokes services located across platforms, enterprises (from architecture and implemented Infrastructure point of view) or geographical locations.

*Example*: A new application can be developed using existing, remote services that may be provided by other applications.

**Distributed System is SOA**: means in distributed system the processes touching multiple applications perfectly co-ordinated with business process system can achieve similar motive.

*Example*: Exposing relevant business functions as service and then encoding the business process inside an application that accesses all services with SOA.

Answer (score -1):

As to DS, there is some definition, communication over machine boundaries using some protocol, and also can be classified to several types, like client-server, p-2-p, etc. SOA can be some distributed system.